# importing 2 modules with use

Tags: perl

I have 2 perl modules every module use the second one i.e
Module1.pm

use Module2

Module2.pm

use Module1

what happen on the background when I load those 2 modules with use
use Module1;
use Module2;

could someone explain  what happen on the background and why I not enter infinate loop ?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: If you're in this situation I'd suggest you should take a look at your current design, as it's broken. A circular dependency in libraries is just wrong. In an interpreted language like Perl you might get away with it, but it's not going to work for a compiled language. You should consider redesigning the affected modules in this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't fall into an infinite loop because of the special hash `%INC`:

> **%INC**
>   The hash `%INC` contains entries for each filename included via the `do`, `require`, or `use` operators. The key is the filename you specified (with module names converted to pathnames), and the value is the location of the file found. The `require` operator uses this hash to determine whether a particular file has already been included.

Also, remember that `use Module LIST` is equivalent to

```
BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }
```

So when the main program uses `Module1`, the following sequence happens:

1. `require Module1` (from package `main`)
2. `require Module2` (from package `Module 1`)
3. `require Module1` (does nothing because `Module1` is already in `%INC`)
4. `Module1->import` (into package `Module2`)
5. `Module2->import` (into package `Module1`)
6. `Module1->import` (into package `main`)